# How do I save the nk.eda_plot into an excel sheet?

Tags: python

Hello Fellow Coders,
I'm trying to extract features of the EDA signal, and plot it . So i'm using the neurokit's function
nk.eda_plot(..) with this I'm able to plot the graph on the jupyter notepad that I'm using but not able to save it in an excel sheet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGDiQ.png)

Would be of great help, if anyone of you is aware of a solution.

Thanks in advance !!!

Thanks and Regards,
Raghu

Explained in the previous section already

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
I do not use NeuroKit, but it seems like it is using MatPlotLib / Pyplot under the hood. Looking at the [documentation](https://neuropsychology.github.io/NeuroKit/functions/eda.html#eda-plot), one can see that it is only possible to extract the *plot*. What you probably want is the NeuroKit function [eda_process()](https://neuropsychology.github.io/NeuroKit/functions/eda.html#eda-process). This returns a Pandas DataFrame, which you can save with the Pandas function [to_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've done some research on NeuroKit and I think I have found a working solution for you. Like I said in my comment, it has to `with eda_process()`.

Below is an example program (not in Jupyter, sorry) that gets some EDA signal and converts the data into a readable Excel file.

```py
import neurokit2 as nk

# create dummy test data by simulating EDA signal
signal = nk.eda_simulate(duration=30, scr_number=5, drift=0.1, noise=0)

# process
signals, info = nk.eda_process(signal)

# convert to Excel
signals.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

I hope this helps!

*Oh, and having a code example of your current approach/context in your question always helps to understand exactly what you need and what you already have. It's quite hard to decipher from your picture what exactly `signals` is, and no one likes to transcribe code from images to test it out for themselves. ;)*